# How can i get the count of in and out?

Tags: python, deep-learning, yolov8

i'm writing a code to get the total object that move in and out and would like to save the count into a database later on. I currently i have this code but i'm not able to get the object count. Keep getting NONE

I have tried this

```
import cv2
import supervision as sv
from ultralytics import YOLO

def main():
    model = YOLO("models/yolov8l.pt")
    
    box_annotator = sv.BoxAnnotator(thickness=1, text_thickness=1, text_scale=0.5)
    line_annotator = sv.LineZoneAnnotator(thickness=1, text_thickness=1, text_scale=0.5)
    
    results = model.track(source="assets/vid2.mp4", stream=True)
    
    line_zone = sv.LineZone(start=sv.Point(600, 0), end=sv.Point(600, 300))
    
    for result in results:
        frame = result.orig_img

        detections = sv.Detections.from_yolov8(result)

        if result.boxes is not None and result.boxes.id is not None:
            detections.tracker_id = result.boxes.id.cpu().numpy().astype(int)

        detections = detections[detections.class_id != 0]

        labels = [
            f"#{detection[3]} {model.names[detection[2]]} {detection[1]: 0.2f}"
            for detection in detections
        ]

        frame = box_annotator.annotate(scene=frame, detections=detections, labels=labels)

        line_zone.trigger(detections=detections)
        line_counter = line_annotator.annotate(frame=frame, line_counter=line_zone)

        print(line_counter)

        cv2.imshow("yolov8", frame)

        if (cv2.waitKey(30) == 27):
            break

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The `print(line_counter)` keep getting NONE but in the `cv2.imshow` i'm able to view the in & out number. But i want to get the in and out number

Comment: Have you update ultralytics Released: Oct 18, 2023

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're trying to reinvent a bicycle a little. Why not use the `persist` argument of the [.track()](https://docs.ultralytics.com/modes/track/#tracker-selection) method?

```
results = model.track(source="assets/vid2.mp4", stream=True, persist=True)
```

It will track objects across frames and assign them IDs as soon as the given ID appears it enters the frame as soon as it disappears it's out of the frame.

Comment: How can i get the id after adding the persist=True ?